# Use Spring Security to add headers to API post

Tags: java, api, spring-boot, spring-security

I have a url for a external api that I want to post json string to. I need to pass the username and password of a valid account to the api as headers, but I don't want to hardcode any username or passwords, I want any user to be able to login and make the post request. I wanted to know if spring security could be used to prompt the user to login then make the post call to the url with the credentials entered?

below is my current hardcoded version without spring security

```
    String Username="admin";
    String Password="pass";

  public String createPost() throws AuthenticateException,ClientHandlerException {

String url = "https://someapi.net/rest/api/2/issue/";

Client client = Client.create ();

client.addFilter (new HTTPBasicAuthFilter(Username, Password));
WebResource webResource= client.resource(url);
//--INPUT is formatted a bit different In my app but I just can't show it
String input = "{
    "fields": {
       "project":
       {
          "key": "TEST"
       },
       "summary": "REST ye merry gentlemen.",
       "description": "Creating of an issue using project keys and issue type names using the REST API",
       "issuetype": {
          "name": "Bug"
       }
   }
}"

String encoded = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString((username + ":" + password).getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));

ClientResponse response = webResource.type("application/json")
        .header("Authorization", "Basic " + encoded) // put the credential in header
        .post(ClientResponse.class,input);
return output;

}
}
```

Comment: Refer this article to add spring security to your end point which encloses the above code https://www.baeldung.com/securing-a-restful-web-service-with-spring-security. Once you have that set up, you can get the username and password from the Principal object.

Comment: @codeMan Okay and I will do that thank you. This principle object is from the current logged in user correct? not the hardcoded auth.inMemoryAuthentication() variables right?

Comment: Yep, that is correct.

Comment: In production env, you'll essentially replace the auth.inMemoryAuthentication() with a database table look up for valid username and passwords

Comment: @codeMan that is the issue I'm trying to avoid. I want any user who has a account with that external api to post to it. I don't want to store or lookup any credentials